# Send several requests via a socket connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Is it possible to connect to a socket, first send a request and receive a response then send another request and receive its response within the same socket connection ?

I want to eliminate the costs of creating new socket connection for each request.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, common even.  It just needs an appropriate protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP connection is an infinite bidirectional stream of bytes. There are no messages/requests at the TCP level. You can send and receive as many bytes as you want. This is even required by many application protocols.